# ASUS Crosshair V Formula-Z motherboard wont POST after BIOS upgrade

Tags: motherboard, bios

After installing a new Crosshair V Formula-Z motherboard the first
startup showed that had BIOS 0508. The ASUS website said that my CPU (AMD
FX6350) was supported in BIOS 0803 or later. Using a USB Stick I upgraded
to 1503. After that it wouldn't POST. I then downgraded the BIOS to
0704.

Now the board has the VGA LED lit and a Q-Code of C6. What does
this code mean? The q-code list published in the manual does not have
any codes starting with C. Is there a link to the complete q-code list?

More importantly, how do I get the motherboard to work, at this point I
can't get to BIOS settings or anything.|

Comment: I would contact ASUS technical support on this subject. If the Q-Code isn't documented in what you have, then unless you find somebody who actually knows, we don't have access to the information. Furthermore if its new then its under warranty.

Comment: I called ASUS tech support (twice) and they could not give me the definition of the Q-Code.   I wound up returning the board and going with a different manufacturer.

Comment: I would post that as an answer.  Simply state that you contacted ASUS and determined the Q-Code is undocumented or perhaps better indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

According to ASUS technical support, the Q-Code C6 (and C5) are undocumented.
They also stated that there is not a definitive list of Q-Codes available on the web.

At their direction I returned the motherboard and got a replacement.